# Cannot modify any Apex class after Salesforce migration

Tags: apex

I have strange issue on the sandbox.
Salesforce did migration on our instance yesterday.

[image: Sandbox Migration]

Today, no one can modify any Apex class. From IDE, Dev Console, Setup.
It throws Internal Server error.

[image: An internal server error has occurred]

Perhaps, anyone faced this issue before. 
I guess, it is related to this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html

Comment: seems strange...there might still be some changes going on in the background...raise a case with Salesforce...

Comment: Have you tried to "compile all classes", found in Setup > Develop > Apex Classes? It might just be a cache issue.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, Yes, I did it. But it was an issue from SF side. We created the ticket and they fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by Salesforce. The ticket was created and SF fixed it.